# insert if not present else update on user's choice android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, development-environment

I've found a few "would be" solutions for the classic "How do I insert a new record or update one if it already exists" but I cannot get any of them to work on user's choice in android

I have a table as follows:
`mytable(Name text,Longitude double, Latitude double)`

What I want to do is add a record with a unique Name. If the Name already exists, I want user choice to modify the fields or ignore it in android.

Can somebody tell me how to do this please?

my code for insert button :

```
public void insert(View v) {
        final String nm = name.getText().toString();
        final String longitude = ln.getText().toString();
        final String latitude = lt.getText().toString();
        // ln.setText("");
        // lt.setText("");
        // insert data into able
        try {
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from mytable ", null);

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                c = db.rawQuery("select (*) from mytable where Name=" + nm, null);
                if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
                    builder.setMessage("Record Already Exists Want to overwrite?");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("YES",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // Do nothing but close the dialog
                                    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
                                    updatedValues.put("Longitude", longitude);
                                    updatedValues.put("Latitude", latitude);
                                    db.update("mytable", updatedValues, "Name="
                                            + nm, null);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }

                            });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("NO",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // Do nothing
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "values updated successfully.",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /* record exist */
                } else {
                    db.execSQL("insert into mytable values('" + nm + "','"
                            + longitude + "','" + latitude + "')");
                    /* record not exist */
                    // display Toast
                    Toast.makeText(this, "values inserted successfully.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            db.execSQL("insert into mytable values('" + nm + "','" + longitude
                    + "','" + latitude + "')");
            /* record not exist */
            // display Toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "values inserted successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

when i insert value with same name it is added . But i what is did is when user enters same name which already exists a alert is buit to ask whether user want to update or ignore .
if he click on yes the records gets updated and if no then nothing happens...

Comment: With a `query`, and an `insert` or an `update`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Post code for what you have done so far.

Comment: @CL. when user click insert if database has record with same name alert is formed to ask if user wants to update or dismiss.

Comment: @Neo i have inserted the code

Comment: See if this the query I posted below helps

Answer (score 1):

First make a query to check if there is a record with the same name like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name='*text*'
```

in here the `name` is the input of your user. Then you check if that query returns a record. If it does, give feedback to your user to set another name or ignore it by updating the returned record.
If it returns no records, you can insert the record into your database.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use `rawQuery` would be

```
c = db.rawQuery("select * from mytable where Name = ?", new String[] { nm });
```

Comment: thanks for it but i want to update the database on user's choice if record exists.

Comment: That's fine but what I gave above is the correct syntax to use the `rawQuery` method. The entire premises is to avoid string concatenation of the where clause for the params. There is a reason behind the 2nd argument which you are sending as null.